# How to make video player function and hit the red bar

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

I have got a basic video player and i followed a tutorial on how to create it, but when you click on the play button, then nothing happens as it does not play the video. Also I have got a red bar on the video as the progress, which is displayed all the time, but i only want it to be displayed on hove, so how can I achieve this as i followed the same youtube video as above.

I have followed a youtube and searched the internet, but i have been unable to fin a solution.

HTML

```
<div class="c-video">
                        <video class="galaxy-video" src="../videoplayer/intro.mkv"></video>
                        <div class="controls">
                            <div class="blue-bar">
                                <div class="blue-juice"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="buttons">
                                <button id="play-pause"></button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </div>
```

CSS

```
.galaxy-video{
    width: 100%;
    height: 700px;
}
.c-video{
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.c-video:hover .controls{
    transform: translateY(0);
}
.controls{
    display: flex;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 5px;
    width: 1245px;
    margin-left: 155px;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    transform: translateY(100%);
    transition: all 0.2s;
}
.buttons{
    padding: 10px;
}
.buttons button{
    background: none;
    border:0;
    outline: 0;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.buttons button:before{
    content: '\f144';
    font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 28px;
    color: #fff;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
.buttons button.play:before{
    content: '\f144';
}
.buttons button.pause:before{
    content: '\f28b';
}
.blue-bar{
    height: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
}
.blue-juice{
    height:10px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

Javascript

```
var video = document.querySelector(".galaxy-video");
var juice = document.querySelector(".blue-juice");
var btn = document.getElementById("play-pause");

function togglePlayPause() {
    if (video.paused) {
        btn.className = "pause";
        video.play();
    } else {
        btn.className = "play";
        video.pause();
    }
}
btn.onclick = function() {
    togglePlayPause();
};
```

Here is a screen shot of the red bar that i wish to only be displayed on hover:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/nN2S0.jpg

Any help appreciated and thanks in advance.

Comment: **mkv** is not a supported format of HTML video.

Comment: Add this <video autoplay muted> but you should look this article https://medium.com/@sundaykuloksun/video-play-not-working-html5-autoplay-policy-beed81d64ca5

Comment: @EmielZuurbier I change the video to an mp4, but it still does not work

Comment: @FerhatBAS i add that, but that muted the video and I checked out that article, but it has stiil not change as the video cannot be played/paused

Comment: There should be an error somewhere. Are you getting a 404 on finding the video's **src**?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier No i am not receiving any error on the video src :/

Comment: Can you create an example which we can reproduce?

Comment: @EmielZuurbier Here is and example https://jsfiddle.net/7wny0o8f/

Comment: does the path to the video actually point to a video that is playable? that path indicates it's relative to the parent directory of the current page

Answer (score 0):

**(1)**

> *"When you click on the play button, then nothing happens as it does not play the video."*

You need to attach a listener to your button (listening for a "click" event).

```
<button id="play-pause" onClick="togglePlayPause();"> </button>
```

Then that should respond to your function `togglePlayPause` like this...

```
function togglePlayPause() 
{
    if (video.paused) { video.play(); btn.className = "pause"; } 
    else { video.pause(); btn.className = "play"; }
}
```

**(2)**

> *"Also I have got a red bar on the video as the progress, which is displayed all the time, but I only want it to be displayed on hover"*

Simply add a "Hover" rule to the CSS of your target element.

```
.myDivID :hover {
 //some hover-related code here...
}
```

The final setup could look like:

a) The target `div` is styled to have zero opacity (now is fully transparent).

```
<div class="blue-bar" style="opacity: 0">
```

b) Then your CSS rules would be like below (where opacity is animated to increase to `1.0`)...

```
.blue-bar{
    height: 10px;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    background: #000;
}

.blue-bar:hover {
    opacity: 1.0;
    transition: transform 1.5s;
}

.blue-juice{
    height:10px;
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
```